# Create an array from a range while ignoring blanks

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, blank-line

am struggling at something basic here...

Using Excel VBA:
Need to create an array from a range (1 dimensional) but the process needs to remove any blanks.

My Code is not working...

```
Sub ReadFilePaths()

Dim b As Long 'counter
Dim rPATHS As Range 'selected range containing file paths
Dim aTEMP As Variant 'initial array to be cleaned of blanks
Dim aFILEPATHS As Variant 'final array containing File Paths of those to be ReFlagged

Sheets("FILES").Select 'select ws where they are listed
Range("B3:B33").Select 'select range of them (30 files max)
Set rPATHS = Selection 'sets range rPATHS to the selection

aTEMP = rPATHS.Value 'Temp Array set to values in list

For b = LBound(aTEMP) To UBound(aTEMP)
        If aTEMP(b) = "" Then
        End If
     aFILEPATHS = aTEMP(b)
Next b
End Sub
```

I'm having one of those days today! Any help greatly appreciated.

Data Input would be

```
Element
C:\Test\myfile1.txt
C:\Test\myfile2.txt

E:\Folder1\Folder2\hisfile1.txt

F:\FolderA\herfile2.txt
C:\FolderC\zfileAV.txt
```

Output in array

```
C:\Test\myfile1.txt
C:\Test\myfile2.txt
E:\Folder1\Folder2\hisfile1.txt
F:\FolderA\herfile2.txt
C:\FolderC\zfileAV.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you cant create 1 dimensional array using range.

If you use range to assing array you create 2 dimensional array - in your example `aTEMP(1 to 31, 1 to 1)`. Try this code with small corrections:

```
Sub ReadFilePaths()

Dim b As Long 'counter
Dim rPATHS As Range 'selected range containing file paths
Dim aTEMP() As Variant 'initial array to be cleaned of blanks
Dim aFILEPATHS() As Variant 'final array containing File Paths of those to be ReFlagged
Dim i As Long
Sheets("FILES").Select 'select ws where they are listed
Range("B3:B33").Select 'select range of them (30 files max)
Set rPATHS = Selection 'sets range rPATHS to the selection

aTEMP = rPATHS.Value 'Temp Array set to values in list

For b = LBound(aTEMP) To UBound(aTEMP)
        If aTEMP(b, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim Preserve aFILEPATHS(i)
        aFILEPATHS(i) = aTEMP(b, 1)
        i = i + 1
        End If
Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that... this works exactly as I wanted.  For future and to help me; should I have used a different method to transfer the file lists to an array?

Comment: @xoPIEMANox: you can write loop and assign value directly from excel to array

Comment: LOL I thought that was what I had done...many thanks for your resolution though

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if they are **blanks**, but doing nothing about it, try this.

```
Sub ReadFilePaths()
    Dim b As Long               'counter
    Dim rPATHS As Range         'selected range containing file paths
    Dim aTEMP As Variant        'initial array to be cleaned of blanks
    Dim aFILEPATHS As Variant   'final array containing File Paths of those to be ReFlagged
    Dim tmpStr As String        'Temporary String

    Sheets("FILES").Select      'select ws where they are listed
    Range("B3:B33").Select      'select range of them (30 files max)
    Set rPATHS = Selection      'sets range rPATHS to the selection

    aTEMP = rPATHS.Value        'Temp Array set to values in list

    For b = LBound(aTEMP) To UBound(aTEMP)
        If Len(aTEMP(b) & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
            tmpStr = tmpStr & aTEMP(b) & "#"
        End If
    Next b

    aFILEPATHS = Split(tmpStr, "#")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The line        If Len(aTEMP(b) & vbNullString) <> 0 Then is falling over as a 'SubScript Out of Range' error....